# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xlwt' on ubuntu server

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, installation, xlwt

I have a python script that uses the module xlwt. Locally the script works fine, and when I tried to run it on ubuntu remote server, it gave me the following message:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xlwt'
```

I installed the module on the server like so:

```
sudo pip3 install xlwt
```

and it installed it successfully. Nonetheless, it gave me the above message.

BTW, I'm using `python 3.6`, and the `xlwt` version that I installed is `1.3.0` (that suppose the support `python 3.6`).
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Which piece of code triggers the error message?

Comment: At the import part I think: "from xlwt import Workbook"

Comment: Unreproducible on Python 3.5.  Please [edit] your question to include precise repro steps. See also the guidance for writing a [mcve].